# Check compiler optimization settings during compilation

Tags: xcode

I would like to check specific compiler settings during compilation. I'm talking about settings set in xCode and used by the compiler.

for example, i would like to check this setting and conditionally compile code

```
#if GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL == 0
    NSLog(@"No Optimization");
#else
    NSLog(@"Optimization enabled");
#endif
```

The above code does not work, does anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is:

```
#define __OPTIMIZE__ 1
```

Which appears to be set whenever `-O` is set with a level above `0`.  If `-O0` is used then this constant is not set.

This was found using:

```
$ gcc -O2 -dM -E - < /dev/null | grep -i opt
```

and:

```
$ gcc -O0 -dM -E - < /dev/null | grep -i opt
```

under Linux.